# Reading data for an output efficiently in Java?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, resources

I have a web application which runs on MySQL, and uses Java, Struts2 and JSP technologies.

There is an algorithm running on it and I want to test its performance (even seconds are important for me.) I will watch the output as a graphic on a page. I will get the information with Ajax and check for new information every second and write it to the graphic.

My question:

One of my classes produces an output for graphic input. What is the best way to communicate this. For example writing output to a database table and the other class will collect that value from there, or writing to a file, writing to database asynchronously (don't know how) and getting the value etc.

I need to do that operation with high performance because that algorithm uses system resources so much and should be run with best performance so I need a solution that doesn't affect my total performance.

Comment: Hi, I took the liberty to make your question a bit easier to read.

Comment: When you say you want to collect and communicate the outputs, is this just within the context of this performance testing? If so, can't it be done on the client side, to avoid using server resources?

Comment: If the classes are in the same process, why not just keep the data in memory? In general, I think it's a bad idea to choose Java if you're doing performance critical stuff. Have you considered implementing part of the app in C++ and interfacing it with the Java app using JNI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you query every second, you're only interested in the latest state which means your algorithm can simply update this state as a variable in memory. The class that produces the output will have access to this variable.

I am presuming your graphic will be updated via javascript. Have the class that produces the output only produce output when something asks for it, by reading the value of the variable and returning it as a JSON string. In your case the Ajax request should query this class (every second). The class will return a JSON string which your javascript will have access to and will be able to use to update the graphic.